# Meaning of "False Positives Per Window"

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, svm, object-detection

In the paper **Histograms of Oriented Gradients for Human Detection (Navneet Dalal and Bill Triggs)** (see link below), to visualize their results, they use a ROC curve, on which the Y axis is TP and the X axis is **FPPW (False Positives Per Window)**.

What is the meaning of this phrase `FFPW`?

I thought about 3 possible options... I don't know - maybe all of them are wrong. Your help will be appreciated:

1. Maybe it is the rate of incorrectly classified negative samples, which is: `(NUMBER_OF_FALSE_POSITIVES / NUMBER_OF_NEGATIVE_SAMPLES)`
2. Or maybe it is the rate of false alarms per true alarms, which is: `(NUMBER_OF_FALSE_POSITIVES / NUMBER_OF_TRUE_POSITIVES)`
3. Or maybe it is the rate of false alarms per true windows in the whle image, 
   which is: `(NUMBER_OF_FALSE_POSITIVES / NUMBER_OF_TRUE_SAMPLES)`

I'll be  glad to know whether one of them is the correct one, or if you know any other correct definition.

Link to the paper:
(https://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to be defined as `NUMBER_OF_FALSE_POSITIVES / NUMBER_OF_WINDOWS`, where the detection window is a `64x128` moving window. Notice in the last paragraph of section 4 it states:

> ... In a multiscale detector it corresponds to a raw error rate of about 0.8 false positives per 640×480 image tested.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same confusion. The authors state that they are using *DET curve*s. When you look at several [examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detection_error_tradeoff) about DET curves you see that x-axis is actually False Positive Rate. That means `FPPW` is `FALSE_POSITIVE_RATE`.

Hence `FPPW = NUMBER_OF_FALSE_POSITIVES / NUMBER_OF_NEGATIVE_SAMPLES`

[image: DET curve]

Comment: So `FFPW` does NOT mean precision, right? You do not divide the number of false positives by the number of windows that "survived" your threshold (which means `(fp + tp)`), but you rather tell what's the rate of retrieved wrong windows, out of all the wrong windows. The precision can still be much lower

Answer (score 1):

They have a window which they move across the image and evaluate if it shows a human or not.
FPPW is a measure of how often they detect something else as a human within their detector window. It describes the quality of their classification in a way that is independent from image sizes or people counts on a particular image.

So basically they count how often their dumb computer says "yes that's a human", when they show it some rock or icecream.

Comment: What you describe here is FP rate. But what is FPPW? Why don't they just call it FP?

Comment: Ah so false positives PER window is not a rate or what?
I basically said the same as Bogatron, his answer is upvoted and mine is downvoted. n1
I don't see a single occurance of FP in that paper. You always need two things for a rate. Something PER something else. W is that second thing. Otherwise you don't have a rate. I guess they just wanted to be precise by naming that second thing. Otherwise I would aks false positives per what? images? datasets? runs? blocks?